# how to import resource editor projects to netbeans 7.2 and execute as jar/jad files?

Tags: netbeans-7, lwuit-resource-editor

how to import resource editor projects to netbeans 7 and execute as jar/jad files?? I am trying to import and execute but I can only open statemachine files and binary files not the actual program files..why is so?

Comment: i have asked this question previously and did not get any answer.But this time i expect quick answer.I think I am more clear in problem statement.

Comment: resourse editor projects imported to netbeans and excecute them as netbeans projects.i am getting error 2 and error 3 often.